# same code works differently loading data from database and using local data

Tags: php, mysql, strcmp

(Yes, the title should have been more understandable but honestly I didn't know how to set it.)

What I am trying to do is creating a online dictionary of Latin. When you search a word the code (I am using some index so don't worry about selectivity) will search that name row by row inside a string (the string becomes an array using *explode*).

I've created a table called 'test' just to practice with this code but it works in the same way of the one of the dictionary: [here the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRGZp.png)

Before trying to load data from database I've checked if it worked locally. It works locally. Here the code:

```
$word_searched = 'puellam';

$string_declination = ('puella,puellae,puellae,puellam,puella,puella');
$array_declination = explode(",", $string_declination);

$check = 0;

foreach ($array_declinazion as $item) {
    if ( (strcmp($item, $word_searched)) === 0 ){
        $check++;
    }
}   

if ( $check > 0) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Then I've tryed to load the data from the database (the table 'test') using the same code. Here the code:

```
$query =  "SELECT * FROM test";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error running query!');

$check = 0;
$string = 'puellam';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $array_declinazione = explode(",", $row['declinazione']);
    foreach ($array_declinazione as $item) {
        if ( (strcmp($item, $string)) === 0 ){
            $check++;
        }
    }
}


if ( $check > 0) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

The first code works perfectly but the second one doesn't even though it's the same way. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Your first one wouldn't work since there is a type in a variable name ;)  What kind of values are getting out of `$row['declinazione']`?

Comment: Yes, I was using other names for the variables when I was working locally but then I've changed them before posting here to make them more understandable. By the way the first code works (with the right names). $row['declinazione'] is a string and contains the declination of the name (the name is puella in this case). It's a list of the word that are part of the singular declination of a name (they are 6 in total) and they are separated by a comma because then I use the function explode to create an array.

Comment: The row in your database has spaces while your string does not. You may want to call `trim` on both strings both strings to remove leading/trailing whitespace before comparing.

Comment: ( (strcmp($item, $string)) === 0 )  to be ( (strcmp(trim($item), $string)) === 0 )

Comment: @MichaelMior I didn't know that spaces can be a 'problem' some time. Thanks for the help, now it works!!

Comment: @RavinderReddy thanks!

Comment: @Bobbe12 Posted as answer for you to accept. Spaces aren't a "problem." You're comparing two different strings so you should expect that they aren't equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need for the second one is this:

```
$string = 'puellam';
// If there is a word that matches $string it will return the row
$query =  "SELECT * FROM test WHERE declinazione LIKE '%$string%'"; // demonstration purposes only. THIS IS VERY UNSAFE!!!! DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!!!!

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query;

if ( $result ) {
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ( $check > 0) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
} else {
    die('Error running query! ' . mysqli_error($conn); // Throw errors if any - It's best to log it instead of "echoing" it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The row in your database has spaces while your string does not. You may want to call trim on both strings both strings to remove leading/trailing whitespace before comparing.

For example, change the `strcmp` to

```
strcmp(trim($item), trim($string))
```